# When is a Cocoa binding 'set'

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I've got an NSArrayController set in my storyboard where I set the mode to Entity Name with a name of Client, and bound the managed object context, selection indexes, and sort descriptors.  My NSPopupButton links to that array controller and when I run I see all the elements I expect on the button.

Now I made a strong @IBOutlet in my code and I'm trying to access the contents:

```swift
let objs = clientArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Client]
print("I have \(objs.count) clients")
```

I tried that code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  They all say 0 clients.  Clearly that's not possible as I have the clients showing in the UI.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to schedule the code to the main loop. The array controller is not filled immediately.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know 'when' it's filled is the question.

Comment: When do you set the observed managed object context?

Comment: Is `automaticallyPreparesContent` true?

Comment: Yes, the prepares content is checked on the array controller.

Comment: @Gargoyle It should be enough to schedule it to the main loop. Then it is filled. The reason is that the work is done with a schedule on main loop, too. So if you do the same, you are behind that. (This is a known behaviour for OS X, but I assume that it is the same on iOS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear` are possibly all called *before* your array controller collects its data from the core data store - hence they (correctly) report a count of zero. To get word of any changes to your array controller's `arrangedObjects` array you could use one of the aforementioned methods to install an observer that watches this object and reports any changes:

```
// MyPopUpController.swift

var ArrayControllerArrangedObjectsObservationContext = "arrayController.arrangedObjects"


func viewDidLoad() {
    arrayController.addObserver(self, 
        forKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", 
        options: .New | .Old, 
        context: &ArrayControllerArrangedObjectsObservationContext)
}
```

You're given the opportunity to respond to changes in `observeValueForKeyPath...`

```
// MyPopUpController.swift

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch context {
        case &ArrayControllerArrangedObjectsObservationContext:
            // Check counts here
        default:
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
}
```

If you only need the observer on start-up, after you've checked the counts, and done whatever you need to do you should then remove the observer:

```
// MyPopUpController.swift

arrayController.removeObserver(self, 
    forKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", 
    context: &ArrayControllerArrangedObjectsObservationContext)
```

Comment: Kinda ugly, but it will accomplish the goal.  Thanks.